# how NOT to escape slashes, sending POST request using volley

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am sending POST request using volley. Request has custom headers and json request body. One of the json values in request body is a URL. When i create a jsonobject the // in URL is sent as \/\/. (e.g. "key1:"http//www.xyz.com" is sent as "key1":"http:\/\/www.xyz.com"
This causes a 400 error. How do i fix this?

Here is the POST using volley:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        try{
            jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Key1","http://xyz1.com");
            jsonBody.put("Key2","val2");

        }
        catch (JSONException e){

        }


        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL, jsonBody,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // handle response
                        Log.d("MAIN","response recd="+response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // handle error
            }
        }) {



            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("CUSTOM_HEADER", "Yahoo");
                headers.put("ANOTHER_CUSTOM_HEADER", "Google");
                return headers;
            }


        };

        queue.add(req);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json values were correctly formatted. Checked by priting jsonbody.get("key")
the slashes are escaped when printing out the json using .toString.

For my case, the 400 error was fixed by adding header:
params.put("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");